# Welcome page/ first launch page using react/next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can you send me some examples of the page which only renders once.
I want to see how others implement this feature.

Since I use next.js I tried saving not in localstorage but using cookies and it works but in prod on vercel I can see this page WHEN I don't have to, it shows it for <1s and then show the correct page.

UPD:

It works but when I how the website using vercel this happends:

First time

1. Shows the welcome page
2. I press the button "NEXT" and I go to the next page
3. If I go back in doesn't allow me and it returns to the page on step 2

Once I close the google tab and reopen my website I:

1. See the welcome page for <0.5s
2. I am transferred to the page where I supposed to at first.

Maybe this is has to do with cookie i use

put the implementation of this page:

```
const firstTime = cookies(props).firstLaunch;

  useEffect(() => {
    const expire = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7776000000000);
    if (firstTime === undefined) {
      document.cookie = `firstLaunch=false; expires=` + expire;
    }
    alert(localStorage.firstLaunch);
  }, [firstTime]);

  if (firstTime === "false") return <LoadingPage title={""} to={"/map"} />;
  return (
    ... <=== welcome page


async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
  return {
    props: {
      firstLaunch: cookies(ctx).firstLaunch,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you share your Next.js implementation of this feature? It's hard to say why it doesn't work without looking at it.

Comment: @Aitwar I don't ask for solving my issue, I just wondering if anyone could send me their implementation of this feature

Comment: @Aitwar added, maybe you can help me. I tried using localstorage but I got the same result, even worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use `getServerSideProps` as `getStaticProps` runs on build time and cookies aren't available then. It's a bit different in development mode - static pages are rerendered on every change, so it may have looked to work properly.

Try this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
   const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie);

   if (!parsedCookies.firstLaunch) {
     return {
       redirect: {
         permanent: false,
         destination: '/first-launch',
       },
     }
   }
}
```

This way you can redirect user on server side without any content flash (0.5s). Your `firstLaunch` page must be available under some route though.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { ArrowIcon } from "../components/ui/icons";
import cookies from "next-cookies";
import { useRef } from "react";

function Home() {
  const cookieRef = useRef<Boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => { <=== I use useRef to make this block run only once
    if(cookieRef.current) {
      const expire = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 7776000000000);
      document.cookie = `firstLaunch=yey; expires=` + expire;
      cookieRef.current = false;
    }
  }, [cookieRef]);

  return (
    ....
  );
}

export default Home;

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const tmpCookies = cookies(ctx)
  if (tmpCookies.firstLaunch) { <=== if it is not my first time
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: '/map', <=== redirect
      },
    }
  }
  return { <==== if it is my first time don't do anything
    props: {}
  }
}


Thank you Aitwar for the idea of using getServerSideProps with redirect
```